# Android app installed to system (firmware) crashes on start but not when installed in data/data

Tags: android, android-ndk, firmware

I have to get my app working for a firmware image. My app works great when installed like a normal app to data/data/package/... but when I include it in the firmware it crashes on start.

This is the first time I am working on a firmware app and I am unaware of the differences and it is very difficult to find anything on Google. In fact I haven't found anything helpful yet.

First I suspected access to the filespace data/data/package/files and remove its use completely but it still crashes. I have put Toasts in to see how far the app is going in its loading process but I only get the very first toast every now and then so I expect it has major problems.

I also took out all use of SharedPreferences and the Bundle but it still crashes right away.

I even took out the whole project basically and only loaded a layout to the MainActivity. Still crashes.

Just for testing I created a simple app which only shows a Hello World and loaded it to the system. It starts without any problems.

I should also mention, my app uses the Android NDK a lot but I'm assuming it crashes before its first use because I don't event get the Toasts from before the first access.

So my questions: Is there any way of debugging an app installed to the system folder? Do I need any special permissions? Do I need to specify "firmware" for the ndk? In general, what are the differences I have to watch out for when creating a system app?

Here the stacktrace:

```
02-26 09:40:42.041: E/Trace(1790): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
02-26 09:40:42.071: D/dalvikvm(1790): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms
02-26 09:40:42.241: D/dalvikvm(1790): No JNI_OnLoad found in /system/lib/libpackage.so 0x4220f7d0, skipping init
02-26 09:40:42.721: D/dalvikvm(1790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 568K, 6% free 13110K/13852K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
02-26 09:40:42.721: I/dalvikvm-heap(1790): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.638MB for 3850256-byte allocation
02-26 09:40:42.731: D/dalvikvm(1790): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 5% free 16840K/17616K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
02-26 09:40:42.771: I/MainActivity(1790): ON RESUME
02-26 09:40:42.951: W/dalvikvm(1790): No implementation found for native Lcom/mypackage/MainView;.MyJNICall:()[I
02-26 09:40:42.951: D/AndroidRuntime(1790): Shutting down VM
02-26 09:40:42.951: W/dalvikvm(1790): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x417ee7d0)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: com.mypackage.MainView.MyJNICall:()[I
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.mypackage.MainView.MyJNICall(Native Method)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.mypackage.MyManager.anotherFunction(MyManager.java:43)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.mypackage.MainView.myMethod(MainView.java:1330)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.mypackage.MainView.init5(MainView.java:525)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.mypackage.MainActivity$LoadViewTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:236)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.mypackage.MainActivity$LoadViewTask.onPostExecute(MainActivity.java:1)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:631)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4833)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
02-26 09:40:42.951: E/AndroidRuntime(1790):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-26 09:40:49.711: I/dalvikvm(1790): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
02-26 09:40:49.731: I/dalvikvm(1790): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
02-26 09:42:13.691: I/Process(1790): Sending signal. PID: 1790 SIG: 9
```

Comment: The only logs that I am getting are that the first call to jni works (because I get a log at the right place) and the second fails.  _E/AndroidRuntime(1790): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found:...._ but nothing more

Comment: Actually, the UnsatisfiedLinkError is not about the second call but a later call. The second call doesn't throw an error but just doesn't do anything as in it returns 0 no matter what I specify as a return value.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, after a lot of headache I found the reason. The native library in system/libs wasn't being updated on install and was using a rather old version. Manually updating the library solved the problem. I will have to talk to the manufacturer about this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what i'm seeing here:

```
No implementation found for native Lcom/mypackage/MainView;.MyJNICall:()[I
```

This means that your implementation is not being included in your code. Ensure that you are packing your JNI implementation and linking it correctly with the app. Also if you are calling `MyJNICall()` then this assumes that code is there.

Comment: This function exists and is called when installed as a normal app. What could the difference to the firmware installation be?

Comment: It could be just how JNI may be treated with within a System app with respect to standard App. Just a guess...

Comment: Any idea how I could figure this out? the logs are not very helpful in this case. There don't seem to be any logs from JNI, just Java. Like the first few functions were called but not actually do nothing but return a default value. Then the function MyJNICall is "not found" event though it is defined just like the first few calls. Very weird.

Comment: Instead move the default value into a property file and just read that file.. that way you don't need the jni code

Comment: For my app to work I do need jni. What default value do you mean?

Comment: You said returns a "default value" where does this come from? Is it a hidden value in the modem or something? Because if its a constant string, then moving it to a property file in your app, you can grab the default value from that file.. You just need to package the file with your app.

Comment: Ah. Sorry, what I meant was that, for debugging purposes, I return a "progress" int from the jni call which always returns 0 even though it was never set to 0. I actually need to do way more than just read a value from my native code.

Comment: sounds like you can remove that JNI call and instead.. use a counter and a timer to do that..

Comment: I am not getting a progress from JNI. I setup actuall needed app data. the "progress" int was just for debugging purposes.